# Show that, if $A$ is PSD, then there is an optimal solution $x_i, y_j$ of the below given optimization problem such that $x_i = y_i$ for all $i$

Tags: optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

I'm trying to prove that for the optimization problem 
$$\max \{\sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij}<x_i,y_j> \mid x_1,\dots x_n,y_1,\dots y_n\in S^{2n-1}\}$$
that if $A$ is PSD, then there exists an optimal solution where $x_i = y_i \forall i\in \{1,...n\}$.

what I have figured out that I feel is going somewhere but I havent shown:

- by cauchy schwarz, you have $-1 \leq <x_i,y_j> \leq 1 \quad \forall i,j$
- you can split $\sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij}<x_i,y_j> = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii}<x_i,y_i>  + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i} A_{ij} (<x_i,y_j>+<x_j,y_i>)$ using the fact that $A$ is symmetric as well.

but i feel like i am forgetting a key feature of positive semidefiniteness that will be the solution of a lifetime.

hopefully someone can help me, hints are also very much welcome! cheers and stay healthy!

last edit: $S^{2n-1} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{2n} \mid \|x\|=1\}$

Comment: If this is over $\mathbb C$, your objective function needs absolute value signs... there’s no reason for a bilinear form to be real valued... so the notion of a ‘max’ doesn’t apply as written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\max \{\sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij}<x_i,y_j> \mid x_1,\dots x_n,y_1,\dots y_n\in S^{n-1}\}
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
\max \left\{
(x_1^H,\dots,x_n^H)(A\otimes I)\left(\begin{array}c y_1\\ \vdots\\
y_n\end{array}\right)
\mid x_1,\dots x_n,y_1,\dots y_n\in S^{n-1}\right\}
$$
The matrix $A\otimes I$ is SPD, so for any couples of vectors $v,w$ we have
$$
(v-w)^H (A\otimes I) (v-w)\ge 0 \implies
\frac{v^H(A\otimes I)v + w^H(A\otimes I)w}2 \ge v^HAw
$$
so $v^H(A\otimes I)w$ is necessarily less or equal than $v^H(A\otimes I)v$ or $w^H(A\otimes I)w$. As a consequence, if the maximum is $v^H(A\otimes I)w$, it is equal to both $v^H(A\otimes I)v$ and $w^H(A\otimes I)w$.

Comment: is $\otimes$ the kronecker product? and is $x_i^H$ just the transpose of $x_i$, or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: yes, $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product, and $H$ is the transpose conjugated operation. If the vectors are real, then it is just the transpose

Comment: fantastic! thank you very much!

Comment: hold up a second! i dont think this works, because you do need voor $v$ and $w$ to have that $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} v_{kn +i}^2 =1$ for every $k\in \{0,\dots n-1\}$. so you cant just take arbitrary vectors $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$ with norm $\sqrt{n}$ that are eigenvectors, right?

Comment: You are partially right. Hold on a sec.

Comment: @Britta corrected

Comment: fantastic! thank you very much! :)